# Magento shop page empty on server migration

Tags: javascript, magento

I migrated my magento site to a new server, but now the shop page is empty. I opened up the console and get "scp_product_extension.js:466 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElements' of null(…)".

To migrate, I followed instructions here: https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_move.htm

I cleared the cache manually through file manager.

The JavaScript code appears to be this:

```
    //SCP: Forces price labels to be updated on load
//so that first select shows ranges from the start
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    //Really only needs to be the first element that has configureElement set on it,
    //rather than all.
    $('product_addtocart_form').getElements().each(function(el) {
        if(el.type == 'select-one') {
            if(el.options && (el.options.length > 1)) {
                el.options[0].selected = true;
                spConfig.reloadOptionLabels(el);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

However, I only get that error when I try to view a specific product or category from the home page. If I simply go to the shop page, there is no error at all...which makes me think the items just didn't get transferred properly (although the categories display on the home page). Unfortunately I don't have admin access at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

**My migrate todo list**, i hope it's useful.

1) Transfer all files to new server without var/cache and var/session folders.

2) Transfer all db tables to new server.

3) Optimize settings in app/etc/local.xml file to the new server.

4) Re-compile php files.
   If new server is a linux, try this code

`sudo php -f your_domain_root_folder_path/shell/compiler.php compile`

5) if you get an

> Recoverable Error: Argument 2 passed to ...

on the admin page, Run this code in db query.

`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
   UPDATE core_store SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
   UPDATE core_store_group SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
   UPDATE core_website SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
   UPDATE customer_group SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
   SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;`